# Discuss the duality relation between $L^p(X)$ and $L^q(X), 1/p + 1/q = 1, $ for $1 ≤ p < ∞.$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

> Let $(X,M, μ)$ be the measure space where $X = \{a, b\}, M= P(X),$ and $μ(\{a\}) = 1, μ(\{b\}) = ∞.$ Discuss the duality relation between $L^p(X)$ and $L^q(X), 1/p + 1/q = 1, $ for $1 ≤ p < ∞.$

My Work:

Here, $\mu$ is not $\sigma$- finite. For $1<p<\infty$ $\sigma$- finiteness of $\mu$ is not needed. Here $E=\{a\}$ is a $\sigma$- finite subset of $X$. So, given a bounded linear functional $L$ on $L^p(X)$, there is a unique $g\in L^q(E)$ such that $g$ vanishes off $E$ and $Lf=\int_X fg \;d\mu$ for all $f\in L^p(X)$.

My problems are,

i) Is my argument correct upto this point?

ii) What else I can discuss for the case where $1<p<\infty$?

iii) When $p=1$, $\sigma$- finiteness of $\mu$ is needed. So, what can I mention for this case here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Further ideas: Determine the dimensions of the (finite dimensional!) spaces $L^p$ for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. This will also give you an answer/hint for (iii).

Comment: How can I determine the dimension? Any theorems, propositions?

Comment: @Mathi Any $f \in L^p(X)$ satisfies $f(b)=0$. Why is that? Alternately, you can see that it is finite dimensional because it is a subspace of the space of all functions $\{ a,b \} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: As @Ian said, each $f \in L^p$ can be written as $f = f(a) \chi_{\{a\}} + f(b) \chi_{\{b\}}$. Now calculate $\Vert f \Vert_p$ using this representation. Your answer should depend on $p$. For $p < \infty$, you will get $f(b) = 0$ as a necessary condition for the norm to be finite. This should allow you to show that $L^p$ is $1$-dimensional for $p<\infty$.

Comment: Ok I understand that $L^p$ is $1$-dimensional, but how does that support towards discussing something for the case where $p=1$?

Comment: @Mathi Here $L^1$ is still 1-dimensional, but its dual is $L^\infty$ which is 2-dimensional.